# When is an selfadjoint operatorvalued matrix with positive semidefinite diagonal elements positive semidefinite as well?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, nonnegative-matrices

We have $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space.

- let's consider a matrix $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_p := (C_{i-j})_{i,j=1, ..., p} \in \mathcal{S_H}^{p\times p}\!\!\,,$ that is a $p\times p$-matrix of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $C_{1-p}, ..., C_{p-1}\colon \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$,
- $C_0$ is selfadjoint and positive semidefinite and $\forall l \in \{1, ..., p-1\}\colon$ $C^*_l = C_{-l}$ where $"^*"$ denotes the adjoint of an operator and $||C_0||_{\mathcal{S}_H} \geq ||C_i||_{\mathcal{S_H}}, \forall i \in \{1-p, ..., p-1\}.$

With that given, the matrix

$$
\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_p = \begin{bmatrix} 
  C_{0}  & C_{-1} & C_{-2} & \ldots & \ldots &C_{1-p} \\
  C_1    & C_0    & C_{-1} & \ddots & & \vdots \\
  C_2    & C_1    & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & C_{-1} & C_{-2}\\
  \vdots &        & \ddots & C_1 & C_0& C_{-1} \\
  C_{p-1}& \ldots & \ldots & C_2 & C_1 &C_0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is selfadjoint, diagonal-dominant (respective $||\cdot||_{\mathcal{S_H}}$) with positive semidefinite diagonal elements.

**Questions:**

1. Is $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_p$ positive semidefinit?
2. Could it be even strictly positive definite (but I guess it doesn't hold, since $C_0$ is not necessarily strictly positive definite) ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How can you hope for invertibility if $C_0$ is not invertible?

Comment: The $3\times 3$-matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2&-a&-a\\-a&2&-a\\-a&-a&2\end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample for 2 and 3 if $1<a\le 2$. Maybe, this question is better for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ Jochen: $C_0$ is invertible, 
@ Sebastian: I don't see why this should be a counterexample, since all "leading main-minors" (führende Hauptminoren) are positive with $a \in (1,2].$ Am I right?

Comment: No, the vector $(1,1,1)^t$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2-2a$, which is negative for $a>1$. We need $a\le 2$ only because of your hypothesis that the off-diagonal terms should not have larger norm than the diagonal terms. For $a=1$, the matrix is therefore not invertible.

Comment: The compact operator $C_0$ can be invertible only if your Hilbert space is finite dimensional.

Comment: This question unfortunately wasn't answered so far. Does someone has an idea now?